# jquery timed popup

Tags: jquery, popup

I would like to create a popup function where, as a user is browsing the website, a popup window would appear and ask if they need help or assistance.  I have tried looking for tutorials, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried searching for jQuery popup?  I found loads of tutorials on them with a quick search.

Comment: Thanks for the replies,  I did do some searches and tried javascript popups but they are blocked.  I ended up using what the poster below answer, http://defunkt.io/facebox/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you'll need to use the [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) method on page load, using the body's onLoad attribute, jquery's document.ready or any method you like. An example, using [facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) as the popup plugin and jQuery's document.ready, would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    timeOut();
});

function timeOut() {
    var t = setTimeout("showPopup();", 3000);
}

function showPopup() {
    jQuery.facebox('whatever you want to ask');
}
```

Comment: Thank you scumah for your help, I ended up using your advice, I tried to +1 you but i still need 15 reputation.  Thank you!

Comment: @user1222186, No problem :) You can't upvote the answer yet, but you can accept it if it was useful :P